# Convert a double array into binary using series

Tags: matlab

I have a series as `[ 7  5  4   3  2   1]` . I want to convert a number into binary sequence by considering the place value of the above numbers. So each number have many combinations like..

```
3 is represented as [ 0 0 0 1 0 0 ] again 3 is represented as [ 0 0 0 0 1 1]
4 is represented as [ 0 0 1 0 0 0 ] again 4 is represented as [ 0 0 0 1 0 1] 
5 is represented as [ 0 1 0 0 0 0 ] again 5 is represented as [ 0 0 0 1 1 0] 
5 is represented as [ 0   0    1   0   0    1]
```

I want to store all values in an array. Can anybody help me for writing Matlab Code for it?